# Can I check if an item exist in a real time database (firebase) without a read rule?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I build an event registration app which add all the participants in the a real time database.

**The Database:**

[image: Database]

To secure my app I have used the security rules which only allow pushing data to the "participants",
I use JSON in order to create the register process.

[image: Security Rules]

I want to return some feedback to the client if she/he enter an email that has already been registered.
Can I do it without open a reading option on the "participants"?

Comment: Very nice question. Maybe one approach is to keep a public list of all registered participant's hashed emails and compare user's entered value against those hashes.

Comment: And then giving reading only to that list? @IvankaTodorova

Comment: Yes, this way you're not exposing your user emails database and have the way to present message to their users if an email already exists.

Comment: You know of any guide how to hash lists in real time database? @IvankaTodorova

Comment: @AvivLiberman Hashing emails with `MD5`/`SHA1` with a salt (that you keep as env variable in firebase) might be sufficient. Also you can take a look at [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/202025/172840) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26108341/firebase-security-rule-and-check-for-unique-records?rq=1).