# How retrieve all values when the value is duplicate just take one value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

hier is my firebase  Model

```
"messages" : {
"Johnny_peter" : {
   "-KsjbzGUO90vejwHpzqx" : {
      "message" : "how are u doing",
      "user" : "peter",
      "userName" : "peter"
}
},
"guy_johnz" : {
 "-Ksj5vkO5H4qeleFqojh" : {
     "message" : "merci",
     "user" : "guy",
     "userName" : "steve"
}
"guy_steve" : {
 "-Ksj5vkO5H4qeleFqojh" : {
     "message" : "merci",
     "user" : "williams",
     "userName" : "steve"
}
```

"steve" is duplicate, I want to retrieve only one time the value of username.
I'm using following code

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference messagesRef = rootRef.child("messages");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : ds.getChildren()) {
                String userName = dSnapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", userName);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
messagesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

how retrieve all value of userName and when the value is duplicate , just take only one value.
I want this output:
peter,
steve

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism to retrieve only one node that has a specific value. The most common way to solve this is to store the messages under the `userName` property. So `/messages/steve/-Ksj5vkO5H4qeleFqojh`, etc. This automatically ensure there is only one node to look in when you want the messages for steve.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen, I've updated my post, I dont want to retrieve a specific value but all userName value.
I want this output:
peter
steve

Comment: You can't the query is doing what it has to do, you have to make sure the values are unique when created or make them unique for the user searching

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent Firebase from retrieving the duplicate user name without creating a dedicated data structure for that.

But you can drop the duplicate names in your Java code:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : ds.getChildren()) {
            String userName = dSnapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class);
            if (!names.contains(userName)) {
                Log.d("TAG", userName);
                names.add(userName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this isn't a very efficient way to retrieve a list of unique user names. If you want just that, you should consider modeling a data structure for precisely that use-case. See:

- [Firebase android : make username unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique)
- [How do you prevent duplicate user properties in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294478/how-do-you-prevent-duplicate-user-properties-in-firebase)
- [Enforcing unique usernames with Firebase simplelogin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970681/enforcing-unique-usernames-with-firebase-simplelogin)
- [What Firebase rule will prevent duplicates in a collection based on other fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260476/what-firebase-rule-will-prevent-duplicates-in-a-collection-based-on-other-fields)